# An unhandled exception occurred: Must use import to load ES Module

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I am trying to resolving some vulnerability issues in dev angular, These are internal dependecies so I have add resolutions in package.json file. After that when I do ng serve I am getting below error

```
              An unhandled exception occurred: Must use import to load ES Module: 
              C:\..\..\node_modules\strip-ansi\node_modules\ansi-regex\index.js
              require() of ES modules is not supported.
              require() of C:\kowshik\orch-ui\node_modules\strip-ansi\node_modules\ansi- 
              regex\index.js from C:\..\..\node_modules\strip-ansi\index.js is an ES module 
              file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": 
              "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
              Instead rename C:\..\..\node_modules\strip-ansi\node_modules\ansi-regex\index.js 
              to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": 
              "module" from C:\..\..\node_modules\strip-ansi\node_modules\ansi- 
              regex\package.json.
```

Steps I followed

1. I have added resolutions in my package.json.

   ```
                  "resolutions": {
                    "ansi-regex": "6.0.1",
                    "glob-parent": "6.0.2",
                    "set-value": "4.1.0",
                    "url-parse": "1.5.8",
                    "minimist": "1.2.6",
                    "querystring ": "6.10.3",
                    "node-forge": "1.3.0"
                  },
   ```
2. removed the node_modules
3. npm cache clean
4. npx npm-force-resolutions
5. npm i

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Look like your source code not allow to import packages which uses `require()` syntax

So, Adding "`type": "module"` in the `package.json` will enables ES 6 modules. For more info, see [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/esm.html#esm_enabling)

I hope it will solve your issues